# ORA-39166: Object owner.table_name was not found or could not be exported or imported

Tags: impdp, expdp, imp

im contacting you please because i have a problems with import/export schema.
first step i exported the Schema1 to another database using this script :

cat imp_Schema_AAAA.par

userid='/ as sysdba'

directory=MIGEXPORT

dumpfile=Schema_Schema1_%U.dmp

logfile=impdp_Schema_Schema1.log

TRACE=1ff0300

METRICS=Y

REMAP_SCHEMA=Schema1:Schema2

logtime=all

the export/import passed successfuly but when i compared the schemas tables on the two databases i fount that the number on destination database less than source database.
so i tried to export missing tables by expdp/impdp and exp/imp, but i have the below error:
ORA-39166: Object shema1.table1 was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-39166: Object shema1.table2 was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
FYI: i checked on the source db these tables exist

i need you help please

Thank You